# SUMPRODUCT Not working well

Tags: excel-formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Table_owssvr3[Status Updated],ROW(Table_owssvr3[Status Updated])-ROW(Table_owssvr3[[#Headers],[Status Updated]]),,1))*(Table_owssvr3[Status Updated]=$F$8),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Table_owssvr3[Owner Department],ROW(Table_owssvr3[Owner Department])-ROW(Table_owssvr3[[#Headers],[Owner Department]]),,1))*(Table_owssvr3[Owner Department]=G7))


=SUMPRODUCT((Table_owssvr3[Status Updated]=$F14)*(Table_owssvr3[Owner Department]=G$13)*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Table_owssvr3[[#Headers],[Status Updated]],ROW(Table_owssvr3[Status Updated])-MIN(ROW(Table_owssvr3[Owner Department])),0))))
```

I have a problem with this formula in excel. The second one fixed one of the fields that are off but introduced a new field with a miscalculation. I am trying to check the count of the row with both status updated and owner department as criteria. It leaves two fields one with an over count by 1 and another under count by 1. I checked all input and it has no extra paces or characters.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the second formula and worked well. Maybe is an space.
This formula is easier to use:

=COUNTIFS(Table_owssvr3[Status updated],$F14,Table_owssvr3[Owner Department],G$13)

Comment: I have a filter applied on the date and I don't want to cont all the values, I only want to count the visible.

Comment: When I need somethig like this I add a colum "Filter" to the table with =SUBTOTAL function. In this example: =SUBTOTAL(103,Table_owssvr3[@[Owner Department]]) then add a condition to countifs() function: =COUNTIFS(Table_owssvr3[Status updated],$F14,Table_owssvr3[Owner Department],G$13,Table_owssvr3[Filter],1)

Answer (score 0):

The subtotal funtion return error in all cases. You can reduce the formula with the same results:

=SUMPRODUCT((Table_owssvr3[Status updated]=$F14)*(Table_owssvr3[Owner Department]=G$13))